# Ionic 5 Http failure response for (unknown URL): 0 Unknown Error in an ionic capacitor. when calling API on the simulator

Tags: ios, angular, http, ionic-framework, capacitor

I have an ionic 5 capacitor application that calls a .NET Core backend API. It works correctly on **chrome browser** and **android devices**, (emulator and real device) after build.

When I run using this command **ionic cap run ios -l --external** it's working fine REST API on IOS simulator.

But If I run this command **ionic cap build ios** after that run simulator then REST API not working.

Have searched many solutions on google and applied in the application code but have not found any solution. Please help me how can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: This usually happens if the device/emulator/simulator is unable to connect to the internet or your local network

Comment: Hello, @IkennaAnthonyOkafor Thanks for the reply. But REST API is working in the android emulator and also working in the IOS simulator using the live reload command. (Not working REST API when make IOS build).